# Remove string part in a variable containing date in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string variable that holds the value of `"02/04/2018 to 08/04/2018"`.

```
string dateRange = "02/04/2018 to 08/04/2018";
```

I have a function in `c#` that gets all the date within the range of `02/04/2018 to 08/04/2018` as per below.

```
public string getDateRange(string dateRange) {
    var selectedDates = new List<DateTime?>();

    for (var date = Convert.ToDateTime("02/04/2018");
         date <= Convert.ToDateTime("08/04/2018");
         date = date.AddDays(1)) {
            selectedDates.Add(date);
        }
    foreach (var date in selectedDates) {
        Console.WriteLine(date);
    }

    return selectedDates;
}
```

What I want to achieve in this method is to remove the word `to` in the date range and pass the starting date and ending date separately. Can someone please help ?

Comment: Note that `Convert.ToDateTime` will fail if used outside of your culture - is it the 2nd of April or the 4th of February? Of course, this may not be a problem for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `String.Split()` to separate the dates:

```
public string[] separateDates(string dateRange)
{
     string[] dateSplit = dateRange.Split(new string[] { "to" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     return new string[]{dateSplit[0].Trim(), dateSplit[1].Trim()};
}
```

The method returns a string array that holds the first (`"02/04/2018"`) and the second date (`"08/04/2018"`):

```
static void Main()
{
     string dateRange = "02/04/2018 to 08/04/2018";
     string[] myDates = separateDates(dateRange);
     string firstDate = myDates[0];//"02/04/2018"
     string secondDate = myDates[1];//"08/04/2018" 
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have implemented my method that separates the dates into your method:

```
public List<DateTime?> getDateRange(string dateRange)
{
    var selectedDates = new List<DateTime?>();
    string[] dateSplit = dateRange.Split(new string[] { "to" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (var date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateSplit[0].Trim());
            date <= Convert.ToDateTime(dateSplit[1].Trim());
            date = date.AddDays(1))
    {
        selectedDates.Add(date);
    }
    foreach (var date in selectedDates)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }

    return selectedDates;
}
```

The method now returns `List<DateTime?>` instead of `string` because the type of `selectedDates`  is `List<DateTime?>`. I also made a modification to the console output, now the dates are printing to the console in the following format `dd/MM/yyyy` (e.g. `02/04/2018`).

Comment: Yes. Its working fine. But one small issue, with this code : `for (var date = Convert.ToDateTime(fromDate); date <= Convert.ToDateTime(toDate); date = date.AddDays(1))
                {
                    selectedDates.Add(date.ToString());
                }
            foreach (var date in selectedDates) {
                 
                Console.WriteLine(date);
            }`

Comment: Its printing the date as : `02.04.2018 00:00:00`. I have specified the string to `dd/MM/yyyy`. It just removes the 00:00:00 but keeps the dot in between.

Comment: Where have you specified `dd/MM/yyyy`? `Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));` ?

Comment: you can make your call inline by using `return dateRange.Split(new string[] { "to" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: @john : I have specified it here : `selectedDates.Add(date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));`

Comment: @jones do you want your method to return anything or just to write the dates to the console.

Comment: Actually, I have a data table which contains a list of date in the format of dd/MM/yyyy. 

So I'm just checking if the list contains a list of the `selectedDates` in the format of `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: @jones are you pleased now with my solution?

Comment: @SlavenHvar : Yes. Your solution works like charm. I am marking your answer as accepted. Thank you loads bro :)

Comment: @jones I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

[`LastIndexOf`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/lastindexof): This method searches strings from the right. It finds the location of the last occurrence of a letter or substring. It is the reversed version of IndexOf.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   string str = "02/04/2018 to 08/04/2018";
   int pos = str.LastIndexOf("to");
   string result = str.Substring(0, pos) + "  " + str.Substring(pos + 2);
   Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://rextester.com/HKDJ86812)

*Its printing the date as : 02.04.2018 00:00:00. I have specified the string to dd/MM/yyyy. It just removes the 00:00:00 but keeps the dot in between.*

Here is the little amendment to fix that:

```
 Console.WriteLine(date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Comment: What would you say the benefit of using `LastIndexOf` over `IndexOf` is in this case? Or is it just personal preference?